# SQL Server Equivalent of Bulk Collect in Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, bulk-collect

I want to replicate the following code in SQL Server.  I've had a look around and it seems like the only option is to just use a straight cursor, but is there a better way:

```
DECLARE

    CURSOR cursor1 IS
    SELECT *
    FROM table1;

    TYPE cursor_aat IS TABLE OF cursor1%ROWTYPE;        

    l_cursor cursor_aat;
BEGIN        
    OPEN cursor1;

    LOOP

        FETCH cursor1
        BULK COLLECT INTO l_cursor LIMIT 200;

        FOR INDX IN 1 .. l_cursor.COUNT LOOP
            IF (CheckSomeData() = 0) THEN           
                INSERT INTO new_table
                (col1, col2)
                values
                (l_cursor(INDX).col1, l_cursor(INDX).col2);

                INSERT INTO new_table2
                ...

            end if

        END LOOP;

        EXIT WHEN l_cursor.COUNT < 200;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temporary table and a cursor if you want to do 200 rows at once.