# Issue in Converting composite type of Oracle to Postgres and Bulk collect compatible equivalent in Postgres

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, bulk-collect

In Oracle we have a function where we are using bulk collect to fetch data and store in a variable like.

```
      SELECT DISTINCT emp_id
      BULK COLLECT INTO v_emp_array
      FROM   emp_details;
```

where v_emp_array is a type:

Oracle:    `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE v_emp_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);`

Please help to get this functionality in PostgreSQL.

Being new to these, I am not able to find the correct syntax for it.

Comment: there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533802/sql-server-equivalent-of-bulk-collect-in-oracle)

Comment: @PrashanthBenny Similar is not helpful. Especially when they relate to a different DB vendor.

Comment: as far as I know OP needs SQL query. right?

Comment: They are after Postgres. Your link is SQL server to Oracle. ??

Comment: Try using arrays. Documentation. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

```
do $$
declare
v_emp_array varchar[];
begin
select array(select distinct emp_id from emp_details) into v_emp_array;
end;
$$;
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Also, try to avoid answering a duplicate question. If you can, flag it as duplicate or comment on the question as such.